# Is there a way I can fadeIn custom content of a InfoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, infowindow

I have a listener set on `click` for the markers I create no GoogleMaps (V3 API). When it is clicked, first I load the infowindow with some simple plain HTML with a "loading" gif.

Then I call a method, that grabs the content via ajax and calls `infowindow.setContent(data)` with the loaded `data`. But the transition between animated gif and the new loaded content is rather ugly. Is there a way I can make this a fadeIn/fadeOut?

Here's the code for the function that loads the content:

```
function load_infowindow_content(infowindow, user_id){
    $.ajax({
        url: site_root +'usuario/map_infowindow/' + user_id,
        success: function(data) {
            infowindow.setContent( data );
        }
    });
}
```

Looked around and didn't find anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about jQuery’s `[.fadeIn()]`(https://api.jquery.com/fadein/)?

Comment: Sure, but in what object, in what context? I'll add some code.

Answer (score 1):

You can append your data to a div container with a specified id and then let it fade in using jQuery’s `.fadeIn()` method. Since the object hasn’t been invisible before, you might have to hide it first to then let jQuery make a transition from the container not being visible to being fully visible, like so:

```
$("#mapContentContainer").hide().fadeIn("slow");
```

**EDIT**

A more GoogleMaps specific way has been described on [Google Maps API V3 InfoBox using jQuery fadeIn and fadeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7789656/1791820) (kudos to [Intheblue25](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988616/intheblue25)):

»It is actually possible to fadein the infobox, you have to override the draw function in the infobox.js file like this:«

```
var oldDraw = ib.draw;
ib.draw = function() {
    oldDraw.apply(this);
    jQuery(ib.div_).hide();
    jQuery(ib.div_).fadeIn('slow'); 
}
```